# ERROR while deploying a war in JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have to Deploy a war file in jboss. But it is using webservices. While deploying I get the following Error. Any Suggestions is appreciable.

```
14:32:32,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mastersetup.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mastersetup.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "mastersetup.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:536)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:116)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:128)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generatePackageInfo(WrapperClassGenerator.java:247)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generate(WrapperClassGenerator.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:669)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:638)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:540)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:252)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:453)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:333)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.visit(int, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1678) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:52)
    ... 29 more

14:32:32,711 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 4) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "mastersetup.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"mastersetup.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"mastersetup.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"mastersetup.war\"
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.visit(int, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.String;)"}}
```

Comment: Try upgrading the asm library to the most recent version will get rid of the error message. e.g, `asm-3.1.jar`

Comment: No its not working.Still the same error

Comment: this was previously deployed in tomcat with shared libraries for web services.Is there a complexity to move from tomcat to jboss mainly the shared jars